# MQTT.js wss connection failed in browser

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, wss

I am coding a browser app by using the react framework. In this app mqtt topics are subscribed. I am using the MQTT.js package. If I am running the app in the browser (Edge and Firefox tested) by using an https connection I am forced to using secure websocket (wss) connections. If I am forcing the browser to use an http connection the websocket connection (ws) works fine. But with wss the connection fails:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://serveradress.tld:8084/mqtt' failed`

The wss connection to the broker works also fine from a standalone MQTT client (MQTTX). But it does not work from an webclient like hivemq or mqttx web either.

Here my code for connecting the mqtt broker:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt/dist/mqtt');
var mqttOptions = {
  protocol:  'wss',
  keepalive: 20,
  clientId: "mqttjs_" + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
  path: "/mqtt/,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
const mqttUrl = "wss://serveradress.tld:8084";

var mqttClient = mqtt.connect(mqttUrl, mqttOptions);
```

I do not need to verify the certificates because I am running the connection in a closed network. I am thinking, that the option "rejectUnauthorized: false" accepts this?

Any recommendations how I can debug this?
Thank in advance!

nico

Comment: is `WebSocket connection to 'wss://serveradress.tld:8084/mqtt' failed` the full extent of any error message you get? If not, try a browser that may give more information about the failure

Comment: Yes, thats the full msg I get from Edge and Firefox. I tried to debug by using

```mqttClient.stream.on('error', function (error) {
  // This does trigger when the URL is invalid
  console.error('Connection error:', error);
});```

By this I get a really big object without a understandable (for me) content.

Comment: Maybe put the error object on pastebin and comment a link, if its too large for the post.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to stringify a complete error object. Here you find what I was able to extract:
https://pastebin.com/Gk0X2MMW

Comment: The connection in the standalone MQTT client works fine with this settings:
https://ibb.co/wZq6HMh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a fault in the broker configuration. The broker (EMQX) was not using the correct certificates because the listener was only defined for the SSL connection on port 8883.
After defining the path to the certificates for the WSS listener, the connection was successfully established.

Answer (score 1):

When running in the browser, the JavaScript code has no control over the TLS/SSL handling, all that is done by the browser.

The browser will also not present a screen asking you to accept an invalid certificate as it does when accessing a HTTPS page.

You ONLY option (other than using a cert issued by "real" CA) is to add either the broker certificate or it's CA certificate to the certificate store of EVERY browser that wants to use the broker. This is so the browser knows to trust this.

How you add certificates/CA certificates to browsers is slightly different for every browser, but usually found under "Security" in the Settings.

Comment: After consultation with our IT admin, we are using CA-issued certs. Anyway, I installed the certs and unfortunately it doesn't work. 
Any ideas to get a more useful debugmsg from the browser?
I am wondering, that the connection to mqtt-testservers in the internet also not working, f.exp. MQTTX webclient to the emqx.io testserver. Looks for me like an browser related issue?

Comment: Look at the network tab in the developer tools, reload the page and check what if any errors are linked to the GET request that will bootstrap the UPGRADE to a WebSocket Connection. Also the Certificate will need to contain the correct hostname.

Comment: Thank you for your patience... Can you give me more information? I find nothing in the network tab related to GET requests.
https://ibb.co/h1t95H6

Comment: After testing the application on different machines we found one which give us more information in the browser console... I do not know why but...
"Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"
Looks like we have some issues in the certificate management in our server infrastructure. I will now explore this...