# Connecting webapp to AWS IoT Core with MQTT.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, mqtt, iot, mqtt.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import mqtt from 'mqtt';

export default function Home() {
  const [mqttClient, setMqttClient] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the credentials from our Next.js API route
    fetch('./api/iot-credentials')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(credentials => {
        // Define the connection options for AWS IoT Core
        const options = {
          key: credentials.privateKey,
          cert: credentials.certificate,
          ca: credentials.rootCA,
          clientId: credentials.clientId,  
          protocol: 'wss',  
          host: credentials.endpoint,
          port: 443,
          path: '/mqtt',
          reconnectPeriod: 30*1000,
          keepalive: 60,
          clean: true,
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
        };

        // Connect to AWS IoT Core
        const brokerUrl = `${options.protocol}://${options.host}:${options.port}${options.path}`;
        const client = mqtt.connect(brokerUrl, options);


        client.on('connect', () => {
          console.log('Connected to AWS IoT Core');
        });
        client.on('error', (error) => {
          console.error('Error connecting to AWS IoT Core:', error);
        });
        
        client.on('offline', () => {
          console.log('MQTT client is offline');
        });
        
        client.on('reconnect', () => {
          console.log('MQTT client is trying to reconnect');
        });
        
        client.on('end', () => {
          console.log('MQTT client disconnected');
        });
        

        setMqttClient(client);
      });
  }, []);

  // Example function to publish a message
  const publishMessage = () => {
    if (mqttClient) {
      mqttClient.publish('my-topic', 'Hello from frontend');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={publishMessage}>Publish Message</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am trying to do a simple connection to AWS IoT Core to publish and subscribe to a topic using MQTT.js library. The pasted code is the connection settup i have build, but it is not working. Can someone please explain to me what i dont understand for this to work?
There are no error messages to work with.

Comment: 'it is not working' - so what doesn't work? no output at all? have you tried logging your `options` to see if it contains all the right values?

Comment: No connection is ever being established. I know this becasue  there is nothing loged using the connect event of the client.on. nor error are bing loged, only  that "MQTT client is offline" and "MQTT client is trying to reconnect" 

I have checked that all the credentials are correct and in right formt.

Comment: I would guess that one issue is authentication; the browser security model [does not permit JavaScript to set certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76454889/11810946) (so `key: credentials.privateKey` etc will be ignored). See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-auth.html#custom-auth-websockets) for more info.

Comment: Is there away to check it really is ignored? I cannot seem to figure this out.

Comment: You can check the source [here](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/main/src/lib/connect/ws.ts#L135) (note that only the URL and websocketSubProtocol are passed). Contrast that with the node version [here](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/main/src/lib/connect/ws.ts#L115) (`opts.wsOptions` is passed). In any event [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html) confirms that the authentication options for wss are "Signature Version 4" or "Custom authentication" (so even if you were using node you cant use certs over websockets)..